# Can the core link field link to path aliases with query string parameters?

Tags: 8

I have a field that I need to support linking to internal pages. One of the main cases for this is linking to a search page with some filters already applied. In this case it is a Solr based search.

Using this url in the field:

`/search?page=1&results=10`

or this, with a facet applied:

`/search?page=1&results=10&facet=topics:15`

does not work. The link just shows as `internal:/` with the paths above after it and the link goes nowhere.

How can I have the link field support query string parameters? Note, using the full domain works, but, that does not port around to different environments (prod stage dev).

Comment: Have you tried [LinkIt module with patch for URL fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkit/issues/2712951) ? - Your examples work for me out of the box with LinkIt module

Comment: On core link fields?

Comment: Yes, core URL fields with LinkIt as FieldWidget. Don't know if it matters, but I've enabled internal and external links

Comment: Oh, and I'm using nodes as link target, don't know if it works for views pages or similar

Comment: Hmm I will look into the patch, but the tests are failing.

Comment: Just tested it with an admin views page, entered `/admin/pages/list?page=1` in the input field and is stored as `internal:/admin/pages/list?page=1` in DB